# При повторной загрузке страницы у анимации меняется fps, в чем может быть причина?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, анимация, vue.js, frontend

Существуют две страницы, например index и about. На странице about есть такая анимация: https://codesandbox.io/s/kwz622xvx7

Суть проблемы в следующем: *именно на локальной версии*, если возвращаться с страницы about на index, а затем обратно на about, fps анимации сокращается с каждым разом.

Когда зашел на страницу about -

[image: about1]

Далее переключился на index -

[image: index]

Далее вернулся на about -

[image: about2]

Не могу понять по какой причине это происходит. Проект на Vue